# Preferred Placement of a Network Collector in a Switched Environment

Tags: network-programming, web-analytics, network-monitoring, network-traffic

I'm not a network specialist so my apologies if i've used some of the domain terminology incorrectly, etc. For web metrics/analytics, we currently use both client-side (js page tags) and server-side (log files) data. Neither gives us "delivery" information (e.g., connection speeds), hence the interest in Network Collectors. We are in a switched environment so installing the N/C as if it were a web server, i.e., on a switch port, won't allow it, i don't think, to see the web server traffic.

After some research, i've learned how to place the N/C by configuring a monitoring port. What concerns me about this is the m/p appears work by duplicating the traffic within the switch.

Is there are better solution for N/C placement in this type of network environment?

Comment: I think this type of questions would better be addressed at serverfault.com

Comment: @ mjv : i thought about that and decided against it because the information is most relevant to Web Analytics people, and from comparing the frequency of the relevant tags, most of those types are at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry Doug, switches nowadays won't falter under this sort of load. The way you have explained is quite OK.

Of course, you could buy a more expensive switch with "NetFlow" sort of support... and have the switch collect the data for you....